# VueJS - Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery

Tags: jquery, sass, vuejs2, mixins

I'm trying to use the following module:

[VueTyphead](https://github.com/mrabbani/VueTypeahead)

I'm getting the following error:

> Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).find(...).typeahead is not a
>   function"
>
> app.js:18068 TypeError: $(...).find(...).typeahead is not a function

My thoughts are that it's because I'm not including Javascript and Bootstrap. So I have done the following in my `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/assets/js/app.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css');
```

But, I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: Did you install vuejs-autocomplete plugin using?
npm install vuejs-autocomplete --save

Comment: @charith This has stopped the `Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery` but still getting.. `TypeError: $(...).find(...).typeahead is not a function`

Comment: Did you require the libraries in your `app.js`?